# How can I remove a key binding so that the cua C-x key binding so that I can have the original effects of C-x?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cua

While in cua mode, I want <kbd>C-x</kbd> to act as if cua mode was not active. I like cua <kbd>C-c</kbd>, <kbd>C-v</kbd> and <kbd>C-z</kbd>. But, I grew accustomed to eMacs use of <kbd>C-x</kbd>, and I want <kbd>C-x</kbd> to remain exactly as it was, with or without a selection.

```el
(define-key cua--prefix-repeat-keymap (kbd "C-x") nil)
```

successfully modifies the value to nil, but cua still strangely affects the functioning of <kbd>C-x</kbd>, if it does anything at all.

I would like a way to completely remove the keybinding because in this case, setting the value to nil does not cause the binding to be ignored.

For the curious... I prefer <kbd>delete</kbd> to cause deleted ranges to enter the yank stack (like the cua <kbd>C-x</kbd> would do). I achieved this with the following:

```
(bind-keys ([delete] . (lambda ()
      "Kill active region to the yank stack.
Otherwise, perform normal delete.
Use backspace for an emacs range delete into register 0."
       (interactive)
       (if (use-region-p)
           (delete-active-region t) ;; yank selection into stack
         (delete-char 1))))) ;; forget singly removed characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Via stack exchange [How to implement remove-key to completely undo the effect of define-key](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17430/how-to-implement-remove-key-to-completely-undo-the-effect-of-define-key/64794#64794), I extracted elisp which successfully removes the key binding.

```el
(defun remove-key (keymap key)
  (define-key keymap key nil)
  (setq key (cl-mapcan (lambda (k)
                         (if (and (integerp k)
                                  (/= (logand k ?\M-\^@) 0))
                             (list ?\e (- k ?\M-\^@))
                           (list k)))
                       key))
  (if (= (length key) 1)
      (delete key keymap)
    (let* ((prefix (vconcat (butlast key)))
           (submap (lookup-key keymap prefix)))
      (delete (last key) submap)
      (when (= (length submap) 1)
        (remove-key keymap prefix)))))
```

Using `remove-key`, all cua reaction to <kbd>C-x</kbd> is successfully eliminated:

```el
(remove-key cua--prefix-repeat-keymap (kbd "C-x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you care at all about <kbd>C-c</kbd>, <kbd>C-v</kbd>, and <kbd>C-z</kbd> ?

If not, then you just want to use `cua-selection-mode` instead of `cua-mode`.